# Why is nothing appearing in my React text/input field as I type?

Tags: reactjs, forms, components

I'm using React 16.13.0.  I want to build a simple search component, that does a search as the user is typing.  I have created ./src/components/Search.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchTerm: "",
            setSearchTerm: "",
            searchResults: [],
            setSearchResults: []
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange(event) {
        console.log("value:" + event.target.value);
        this.state.searchTerm = event.target.value;
        fetch('/coops/?contains=' + encodeURIComponent(this.state.searchTerm),{
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(response => {
            this.state.searchResults = response;
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="searchForm">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    value={this.state.searchTerm}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <ul>
                    {this.state.searchResults.map(item => (
                    <li>{item}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is after the component is rendered, as I type, nothing appears in the search box.  I do see the requests being executed against the endpoint, each containing the letter I'm trying to type.  Any help on how I can keep the entire search term present in the text field as I type is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
this.state.searchTerm = event.target.value;
```

with this:

```
this.setState({searchTerm: event.target.value})
```

And searchResults:

```
this.setState({searchResults: response})
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulRyan, although there still seem to be some issues.  For instance, the fetch is only being done with everything except the last character I typed.  For example, when i type "daveddi", the fetch being done is for "ttp://localhost:3000/coops/?contains=davedd".  Also, where do I get the response?  The response object itself does not contain my iterable list of items.

Comment: Ah yes, the state won't have updated by the time you run your fetch thus you'll get the previous value. Do this ```encodeURIComponent(event.target.value)```. As for the response issue, what does the response object your fetch returns contain?